# How to format a div like pre blocks?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to display some HTML files that have code samples, surrounded by `codeblock` tags. Is there any CSS styling that could display codeblocks as if they were `pre` tags? (respect newlines, respect whitespace, etc)

Comment: And the reason you can't use `pre` or `code` tags is...?

Comment: Correct, thats what I ended up doing. Find and replace "codeblock" with "pre" ... everythings cool now.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Like this

```
div { white-space: pre; }
```

Comment: I'd suggest adding `font-family: monospace;`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get pretty fancy, consider a libraries like [Pygments](http://pygments.org/) or [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/) that will do full syntax coloring, in addition to pretty printing of your code.

Pygments would be implemented in server-side Python; highlight.js works browser side.

OR: use a browser-based "code editor" such as [Ace](https://ace.c9.io/), which will then format/color the code... and just use the control in a read-only fashion.